# Maven Central versions with a red background

Tags: maven

I was updating my version of the javassist library and noticed the latest version ([3.22.0-CR1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist)) on the maven repository site has a red background, but with a quick search i wasn't able to find out the reason for that.

Can anyone please explain what does that red background mean?
[image]

Comment: The link you have given is not maven central. This is maven central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ furthermore the search engine for Maven central is here: https://search.maven.org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it is a **pre-release** version (it isn't a **stable** version).

https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/releases/tag/rel_3_22_0_cr1

[image]